# scrolling up/down depending on which section is on viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a really big headache with my code. I have 10 sections on my page, every section is setting up to have height of the window, so I set it like that:

```
$('.section').css('height', window.innerHeight);
```

so all sections have same height as my window, then I wanted to bind scroll if scroll down and 'first-section' is on viewport, then scroll to 'second-section'. If scroll and 'second-section' is on viewport scroll to 'third-section' etc. and that works but it crashes after fast scrolling...

this is my whole code:

html

```
 <section class="section" id="first-section">

 </section> 
 <section class="section" id="second-section">

 </section>
 <section class="section" id="third-section">

 </section>
 <section class="section" id="fourth-section">

 </section>
 <section class="section" id="fifth-section">

 </section>
```

js

```
var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";

$(window).bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);

    var evt = window.event || e;
    evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;
    var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta;

    if(delta > 0) {
        if ($('#second-section').is(':in-viewport')) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#first-section").offset().top
            }, 800);
        } else if ($('#third-section').is(':in-viewport')) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#second-section").offset().top
            }, 800);
        } else if ($('#fourth-section').is(':in-viewport')) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#third-section").offset().top
            }, 800);
        } else if ($('#fifth-section').is(':in-viewport')) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#fourth-section").offset().top
            }, 800);
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#first-section').is(':in-viewport')) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#second-section").offset().top
            }, 800);
        } else if ($('#second-section').is(':in-viewport')) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#third-section").offset().top
            }, 800);
        } else if ($('#third-section').is(':in-viewport')) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#fourth-section").offset().top
            }, 800);
        } else if ($('#fourth-section').is(':in-viewport')) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#fifth-section").offset().top
            }, 800);
        }
    }
});
```

btw. ':in-viewport' if from plugin and it works great. I know that this selector doesn't exist in real codelife :)

Comment: I think you should just either stop the scrolling of html, body on another event or ignore the events if you're already animating the html, body.

The multiple animations are probably causing troubles.

Comment: I don't know if you must to do it in your own but if you just need to achieve the effect you can use this plugin: http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/